# Listing iOS apps supporting DynamicType: OK? How?

Tags: discussion

I want to share a list of iOS apps that allow customizing font sizes:

- either through support of DynamicType / LargerText system settings
- or have their own settings for font size

(similar to ["How to make text appear larger in various apps in OS X"](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27897/making-fonts-larger-in-apps-under-lion/))

I would absolutely welcome others to contribute to the list.

---

What is the best way to do that?

1. Add a table to [the original question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163399/54644) where it is very relevant (but not asked for directly), and adds much specifics to general statements like "some support, other don't; some are larger, others are the same"
2. Post a separate question, similar to "How to make text appear larger in various apps in OS X"--which is definitely better and easier for others to contribute and reuse

---

Should I definitely mark the question (and/or my answer) as a "community wiki"; how do I decide?

Comment: This seems helpful, but ultimately ill-suited for the site. Any list you make is going to go stale. Who will maintain it? You?

Comment: @IanC. I don't expect too many contributors, and yes I'm ready to organize answers of half a dozen contributors (upper limit in my experience). Is that what you mean by "maintain"?

Comment: Apps come and go. Someone needs to stay on top of the list to make sure stuff that's gone from the App Store is gone from the list. That's what I mean from maintain. It feels a bit like a magnet for advertising too. In general, I am not a fan "big lists of things" on this site. They don't work well with the SE format.

Comment: But it did work pretty well in "How to make text appear larger in various apps in OS X" linked above. How my proposal is different?

Comment: @IanC. See above, forgot to mention you there.

Comment: On that point, we appear to disagree. Because I don't think that worked "pretty well" at all. I don't think you could point me at a CW Q&A on this site that'd I think worked out well at all. But, I'm not authority here, and you should open the question up as a CW question like you proposed and let the community decide! :D

Answer (score 1):

When I created [Making fonts larger in apps under Lion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27897/making-fonts-larger-in-apps-under-lion/), it was partly to learn the answer and partly to try the sort of question that I hoped Community Wiki would work well for. I don't think it was a disaster, but it didn't turn out as great as I'd hoped it would. Maybe your question would take off in that format; if it can, I hope it does. I'd recommend trying, but I'm not overly hopeful it will get a great response. I'd recommend a separate question.

Comment: Thanks. My primary purpose is to share my own findings, hoping they will be useful for others. Don't expect too many contributors, to be honest. Would welcome your opinion: [text listing or a preformatted table format?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/163579/54644) (examples of both are there to compare)

Answer (score 0):

So, to sum up my thoughts from the conversation above: post it. If it's good, the community will vote it up, if they disagree, they'll vote it down. I agree you should do it as CW, organized like that other CW Q&A you linked to.

Comment: Well, I have detailed data on 10-20 apps: support of Dynamic Type / Larger Text / app-specific font size settings, no font resizing at all. My options are: (1) just drop it => no one will ever use it; (2) attach it to the existing question where some people will be able to find it and use for their own reference, but hardly anyone will contribute; (3) create a separate question so that not only people can reuse it, but also have a chance to contribute. So yes, I'm going to go ahead and post it as a separate community wiki question / answer.

Comment: Create a new question gets my vote.

Comment: Started listing the apps I tested [here](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/163576/which-of-ios-apps-allow-customizing-font-size/163579#163579). Still unsure whether to choose text listing or a preformatted table format--any feedback appreciated. Both options are shown there to easier compare the approaches.